# Strange behaviour of string:length function

Tags: erlang

Why does the presence of character 'â' cause this to fail.

```
> Bin = <<"â Hello">>.
> string:length(Bin).

** exception error: bad argument: <<"â Hello">>
     in function  string:length_1/2 (string.erl, line 557)
```

Whereas if this is converted to List, it worked fine.

```
> Str = binary_to_list(Bin).
> string:length(Str).
  7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument for `string:length()` can be a list of integers (where the integers are between 0...1114111) or a binary where clumps of integers must form UTF-8 characters.

There are many ways to represent the character `â` (`small letter a with circumflex`), and two of them are:

1. The Latin-1 integer code `226`.
2. The UTF-8 representation: `195, 162` (or in hex: C3 A2)

   ```
    5> <<195, 162>>.
    <<"â"/utf8>>
   ```

When you typed in your binary, your keyboard probably entered the Latin-1 code for "small letter a with circumflex", and 226 is not the beginning of any valid UTF-8 integer code, so erlang gave you a `bad argument` error.

Next, why does converting the binary to a list work?  In erlang, double quotes are a shortcut for creating a list of integers:

```
6> "abc" =:= [97,98,99].  (exactly equal)
true
```

Whenever you see double quotes in erlang, you should be thinking: "This is a list."  The one exception to that rule is when you use double quotes inside a binary: instead of creating a list, you create a comma separated series of integers:

```
8> <<"abc", 0>>.
<<97,98,99,0>>
```

Adding a 0 is a trick that forces the shell to show you what you really have.  Or, you can tell erlang to quit trying to fool you with the double quotes and just show you the truth:

```
18> shell:strings(false).
true

19> "abc".
[97,98,99]

20> <<226, "Hello">>.
<<226,72,101,108,108,111>>
```

When you convert a binary containing integers to a list (binaries can only contain integers between 0...255), then you get a list containing those same integers, and any list of integers, where the integers are between 0...1114111, is a valid argument for `string:length()`.

Finally, note that `string:length()` doesn't merely return the number of bytes in a binary:

```
23> string:length(<<195,162,97,98,99>>).
4
```

`string:length()` recognizes that the first two bytes, i.e. 195, 162, are the UTF-8 code for `small letter a with circumflex`, and therefore it only counts the two integers/bytes as one character.  On the other hand, if you convert to a list first, `string:length()` returns the number of integers in the list:

```
24> string:length(binary_to_list(<<195,162,97,98,99>>)).
5
```

...which is the same answer you get with `byte_size(Binary)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I'm getting this string as part of HTTP call to my cowboy endpoint. So, I can get ASCII, latin or unicode chars - what is the best way to find the length of string I got?

Comment: @spkhaira, When you say "unicode chars" do you mean UTF-8?  If so, see my additional answer.

Answer (score 2):

Response to comment:

> I can get ASCII, latin or unicode chars - what is the best way to find
> the length of string I got?

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

get_response() ->
    [226,97,98,99,195,162].  %% Remember a double quoted string is just
                             %% a shortcut for creating a list of integers.
%%    ^            ^   ^
%%    |            |   |
%%  latin-1        utf-8
%% small letter a with circumflex

count(Bin) ->
    count(Bin, 0).

count(<<_Head/utf8, Tail/binary>>, Count) ->
    count(Tail, Count+1);
count(<<_Head/integer, Tail/binary>>, Count) ->
    count(Tail, Count+1);
count(<<>>, Count) ->
    Count.
```

In the shell:

```
32> string:length(list_to_binary(a:get_response())).
** exception error: bad argument: <<226,97,98,99,195,162>>
     in function  string:length_1/2 (string.erl, line 557)

33> string:length(list_to_binary([97,98,99,195,162])).
4

34> Bin = list_to_binary(a:get_response()).
<<226,97,98,99,195,162>>

35> a:count(Bin).
5
```

Note that `get_response()` returns a list containing the integer code for `small letter a with circumflex` in latin-1, the integer code for `a` in ascii, and the two integers representing `small letter a with circumflex` in UTF-8. Binaries allow you to specify a `utf8` type, which will match a clump of integers that represents one character in UTF-8.  The `utf8` type will also match single integers in the range 0-127, i.e. the codes for ascii characters.  The second clause of the `count()` function specifies an `integer` type, which will match any other integer, e.g. a latin-1 character with a code above 127.

Binaries also allow you to specify the types `utf16` and `utf32` to match clumps of integers representing characters in those encodings.